# Adding WCF Service Reference when using net.msmq

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service that has an endpoint using the net:msmq binding. I am hosting this service in a managed Windows Service. When I try to add a Service reference from the client, I get the following error:

> ```
> The MetadataExchangeClient instance could not be initialized
> ```
>
> because no Binding is available for
>   scheme 'net.msmq'. You can supply a
>   Binding in the constructor, or specify
>   a configurationName.
>       Parameter name: scheme
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

The config looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfservice.QueuedBehavior"
    name="wcfservice.wcfservice1">
    <endpoint address="net.msmq://machinename/private/queuname" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="WCFService.IServiceContract" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8009/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

EDIT:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wcfService.wcfServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="wcfService.QueuedBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have httpGetEnabled="True" in your service configuration?

Comment: @Steve - Yes I do. Please see edit for the `<serviceBehaviors>` element in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by binding configuration NewBinding0 being something other than netMsmqBinding.